# Why has entering a date changed in 4.7.16? Can it be reverted?

Tags: 4.7, dates

Entering a date has changed in 4.7.16 so the user can no longer drop down the year in order to select a year in the past.  Now they have to scroll through months to go backwards!  Imagine entering a date of birth of (say) 1967 - you have to go back 600 months!!  I'm assuming this is a bug, but rather a serious one from a user's point of view.  Does anyone know how this can be easily reverted to what it was before?  In the meantime I'm avoiding my users....

I have raised problem CRM-20209

Answer (score 4):

There was an issue due to some refactoring around the handling of date fields to try to standardise them. This lead to a problem most notably in birth date fields in 4.7.16 but i'm guessing can be found elsewhere. This issue was raised [CRM-19982](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19982)

I suspect the same fix will most likely work for you. If you have a test site or would like to give a test a shot. I would recommend you look at the changes made to the files in the DAO directories here in the [Pull Request](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9831/files) and make the same changes on your server.

That pull has been merged into 4.7.17 which will be released i think in the next week or so

Comment: I applied the fix and it's working OK now, thanks again

Comment: Excellent good to hear Andy.